# Appending data into array using SharedPreferences on each access of application

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

As SharedPrefereces help us to store persistent data I am using it in my application for storing small amount of data(using [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo/blob/master/TinyDB.java)) for which I don't feel the need of using SQLite.

What I'm doing is taking some value from user and storing it in an ArrayList. As the user exits the application or the OS kills the application and again the application is started I wish to add the new data in the same ArrayList mentioned above.

I don't understand how to search for it but tried and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284705/saving-data-upon-closing-app-and-retrieving-that-data) on SO itself.
Though it did not solve my problem so decided to ask.
EDIT : Code snippet
Adding elements to arraylist on button click

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            place = et.getText().toString();
            if(place.length()!=0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), place + " is scanned.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                placeArray.add(place);
                CalculateLatLong();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Enter place to search.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

In CalculateLatLong()

```
   ...
   TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
   tinydb.putListString("locationName", placeArray);
   ...
```

I want to add `placeArray` to `locationName`
As `placeArray` is initialized to null on each kill of application so everytime its a new list which I want to merge with `locationName` contents.
Do I need to do something by overriding the onPause state of activity? If yes then how?
Thankyou.

Comment: Can you past some code of what you've done?

Comment: @PerunSS added the code..

Answer (score 1):

As you're saving list to database in your function, you only need to add code in `onResume` method. You need to populate `placeArray`:

```
void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getContext());
    placeArray = tinydb.getListString("locationName"); // This will either return saved list (if saved), or empty list
}
```